# How to fan out URL Fetch requests in a timely fashion?

Tags: google-app-engine

Every minute or so my app creates some data and needs to send it out to more than 1000 remote servers via URL Fetch callbacks. The callback URL for each server is stored on separate entities. The time lag between creating the data and sending it to the remote servers should be roughly less than 5 seconds.

My initial thought is to use the Pipeline API to fan out URL Fetch requests to different task queues.

Unfortunately task queues are not guaranteed to be executed in a timely fashion. Therefore from requesting a task queue start to it actually executing could take minutes to hours. From previous experience this gap is regularly over a minute so is not necessarily appropriate.

Is there any way from within App Engine to achieve what I want? Maybe you know of an outside service that can do the fan out in a timely fashion?

Comment: Maybe I could use URL Fetch to directly call front end instances on my own app that in turn call URL fetch on the remote servers? In which case how should I go about sharding the callbacks as is done with the Pipeline API?

Comment: I know this question is kind of old. Since you are talking 1000 url fetches and not 10,000 ... did you look at Prospective Search?
Did you come up with a good solution?

Comment: I ended up doing what I said in the previous comment and using front end instances called by URLFetch to fan out. I also used the principles of https://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/wiki/ScatterPropertyImplementation to decided how much to fan out by.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's probably no good solution for the gae here.
You could keep a backend running; hammering the datastore/memcache
every second for new data to send out, and then spawn dozens of async url-fetches.
But thats really inefficient...

If you want a 3rd party service, pubnub.com is capable of doing fan-out, however i don't know if it could fit in your setup.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the async API? You could then do a large number of simultaneous URL calls, all from a single location.

If the performance is particularly sensitive, you could do them from a backend and use a B8 instance.